# Form autosave while entering data using sessionStorage in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I am using sessionStorage to autosave form data while entering data into the input field.But I cannot able to save the data. If the page is refreshed the data should be present in the input field. Can anyone explain why it is not working?

My form is,

```
<form name="createArticleForm" ng-change="autoSave()">
<input type="text" name="firstname" ng-model="emp.firstname" required>
<input type="text" name="lastname" ng-model="emp.lastname" required>
<input type="text" name="designation" ng-model="emp.designation" required>
</form>
```

Js file:

```
$scope.autoSave= function(){
$scope.emp={};
sessionStorage.setItem('emp', JSON.stringify(emp));
var save = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.emp);
console.log(sessionStorage['emp']);
}
```

Comment: i think ur missed **ng-model**

Answer (score 1):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="myApp">
<div ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <p>Write something in the input field:</p>
  <input type="text" ng-model="emp.firstname" ng-change="myFunc()" ng-model="myValue" />
  <input type="text" ng-model="emp.lastname" ng-change="myFunc()" ng-model="myValue" />
  <input type="text" ng-model="emp.email" ng-change="myFunc()" ng-model="myValue" />
  <input type="text" ng-model="emp.password" ng-change="myFunc()" ng-model="myValue" />
  <p>The input field has changed {{value}} times.</p>

</div>

<script>
  angular.module('myApp', [])
    .controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
      $scope.myFunc = function() {
        sessionStorage.setItem('emp', JSON.stringify($scope.emp));
        $scope.value = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('emp'))
      };
    }]);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: ill change it now

Comment: It is for only one input filed. But I have an Object which is called emp and it contains many input field. What is the solution for  that scenario

Comment: Your code shows error. Kindly please check the snippet

Comment: Hi Velu Dhanesh... I can store object values in session. But If the page refreshed the values entered in the input field lost. Can you Pls give me any suggestion?

Comment: get that values and store in ng-model variable in constructor

Comment: can you plz give a demo

Comment: @dijofrancis Please refer jsfiddle link    https://jsfiddle.net/kuo8jvxL/3/

Comment: please try local

Comment: Why you are using two ng-model for the input field

Comment: Your code working perfectly in jsfiddle. But it is not working in my code. I don't know the reason/

Comment: for data binding